# The CKEditor control will not show

Tags: ckeditor

I have just downloaded the newest version of CKEditor and placed the ckeditor folder in the root of 2 sites ks1.dk and ks2.dk.
I then tested CKEditer by showing the sample page.

On http://xxx1.xx/ckeditor/samples/index.html all looks beautiful.
BUT on http://xxx2.xx/ckeditor/samples/index.html the editor control does not show up. All the other stuff is showed as on ks1.dk but not the editor control it self.

Does anyone have suggestions for how I solve the problem?
The sites is located a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu 14.4 LAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem in a radical way.
I dropped the virtual machine and build a new.
This time I have no problems.
My conclusion is that I had some problems with the rights or something like that.